# Can SupressMessage be used instead of SecurityCritical (in some situations)?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing my own managed implementation of ComTypes.IStream, and I have found several examples on how to do that, but I have noticed that while in some, the SecurityCritical attribute is used, while on another one SupressMessage is used.

I have read the MSDC documentation on the two attributes, and the way I understand this is that SupressMessage will only supress a specific warning/error/whatever, but SecurityCritical will supress all of them (in addition to not asking for any kinds of permissions - which I do not need). Kind of like how you can catch a specific exception or you can put a catch all block.

With this in mind, the way I see it, if I know what warnings/errors to supress, it is virtually the same whether I use SecurityCritical or SupressMessage. I also understand that using SecurityCritical in such situations is the same as using an electric drill to pop a balloon.

Am I correct in assuming this, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: These attributes are entirely unrelated. `SuppressMessage` tells an analyzer to keep quiet about what it might perceive to be a violation of a rule; `SecurityCritical` marks a member as, well, doing security critical things. The former has no runtime impact at all, the latter does (when Code Access Security is in effect, at least). It might be the case, depending on how an analyzer rule is written, that adding `SecurityCritical` might skip or satisfy a particular rule, but that is a secondary effect, not its actual purpose.

Comment: I have seen that attribute put on IStream Read and Write methods with the justification "calls Marshal.WriteInt32 which LinkDemands, takes pointers as input". Now since those methods work just fine without SecurityCritical attribute (i.e. the streams are being read and written), is it safe to assume that it is not needed at all?

Comment: That will work fine as long as your code runs with full trust, which is the majority of code these days. You only really need to bother with properly applying the security attributes if you care about partially trusted code being able to use your assembly. (Which I personally never do, to be honest.)